# karma-browserify with angularjs unit tests: name collision on 'module' causes 'object is not a function' error

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, browserify

I have an angular app that I am testing with karma unit tests and I am attempting to add karma-browserify so that I can require npm modules in my unit tests.

Once I added the browserify preprocessor to my karma.conf.js config file my tests began to break, even though I have not even tried to require any modules yet.

I get the following error:

```
object is not a function
```

If I follow the trace I see that the line causing the error is in the browserify bundled js temp file on a call to 'module'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just saw an older post with same question so I answered it there as well:
 [angular mock `module` resulting in '[Object object] is not a function'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968320/angular-mock-module-resulting-in-object-object-is-not-a-function/25286008#25286008)

Change the call to load the app in the unit test from:

```
beforeEach(module("app"))
```

to:

```
beforeEach(window.angular.mock.module("app"))
```

This is a documented issue here which appears unlikely to be fixed:
https://github.com/xdissent/karma-browserify/issues/10
I hope this doesn't cost you a day like it did me.